# Laravel Carbon issue on certain date only

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon, setlocale

I have a problem that occurs only with a specific date ... I have tried the code with a wide variety of dates and they all work, except 2020-03-14, when trying to display that date in local format using formatLocalized () no information is displayed.

Here is the code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$date= "2020-03-13 06:30:00";
$fecha = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date);                                                            
$fecha = $fecha->formatLocalized('%A, %d de %B del %Y');
$fecha = ucfirst($fecha);
```

Shows:
Viernes, 13 de marzo del 2020.

But when I change it to $date to "2020-03-14 06:30:00", it shows nothing.

Please try to reproduce it, thanks!

Comment: Hi, please add some more information to your question: Which operating system and version do you have? What version of PHP do you have installed? Which version of Laravel are you using? It's hard to replicate a problem without this information.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated this code block and used "2020-03-14 06:30:00" and I got this output "Sábado, 14 de marzo del 2020".

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$date= "2020-03-14 06:30:00";
$fecha = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date);
$fecha = $fecha->formatLocalized('%A, %d de %B del %Y');
$fecha = ucfirst($fecha);
```

Are you sure there isn't something you are missing?

Comment: It was simpler than I thought, the problem was related to character encoding. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Glad you have it working now. You can always reach out if you need any more assistance

Answer (score 0):

I have found it, the problem was not only on that date but on all dates corresponding to Wednesday and Saturday, due to the accent (miércoles / sábado). I added a line to encode utf-8 and the problem has been resolved. Thank you!.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$date= "2020-03-14 06:30:00";
$fecha = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date);
$fecha = $fecha->formatLocalized('%A, %d de %B del %Y');
$fecha = utf8_encode($fecha);
$fecha = ucfirst($fecha);
```